# Convert timedelta to floating-point for entire column in data frame

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I need to Convert timedelta to floating-point for every cell in a column of my data frame. Here is how you do it for single cell:

```
time_d = datetime_1 - datetime_2
number_of_days = float(time_d.days)
```

But when `.days` is applied to entire column this error appears:

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'days'
```

I'd like the date difference to be in days to be used in future calculations.

Comment: just use the `dt` accessor; `.dt.days` instead of only `.days`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.dt.days`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.days.html) for processing `Series`:

```
df['column'] = df['column'].dt.days
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df['column'] = df['column'].map(lambda x: float(x.days))
```

Comment: @thefirstreal: nope, you don't need a lambda here, see my comment.

Comment: So both work, but which is better and for what reason?

Comment: @thefirstreal: using the `dt` accessor should be preferred here since it uses built-in functionality (which is vectorized/more efficient). apply/lambda has to be used if you don't have a vectorized option at hand.

Comment: @MuhammadJunaidHaris: why is your lambda here generic? also, since it's neither more efficient nor more readable than dt, why use it?

Comment: That is generally what I was thinking too. Are either of the options faster? @MrFuppes please submit your answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @thefirstreal, built-in should be faster. have a look at [timeit](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/timeit.html) if you want to check for your use-case. jezrael already posted my comment as an answer, I'm fine with that ;-)